# using AS3 can I get all the references of a child and nulling them at the same time I remove the child from the display list?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am facing a problem with clearing the memory. I am making a game where there are many tanks on **Stage**, and each of them has a variable inside called **Enemy**. **Enemy** is a reference to the hostile tank, which I specify through a function. My problem is when a tank (on Stage) is removed from the display list, the other tanks whose **Enemy** were set to reference this tank still act as if it is there. I know the solution, but I don't know how to implement it in this case. I must Null all the references of the removed tank, but the problem is I don't know which of the other tanks had that tank as a reference and which did not.

So, I was thinking, when I want a tank to be removed:

1. Get all the references to it
2. Null all of them
3. Remove the tank

How can I get all the references, knowing only the tank I want to remove? 
Thanks In Advance. This is my first participation on SO.

I've thought of this code, but is there any other more efficient way?

All tanks have the same parent, so inside each tank on an Enter-frame listener function:

```
if (enemy!=null&&parent.contains(enemy)==false){
   enemy=null;
}
```

Comment: All objects are passed as pointers, the object has no idea what has a pointer to it, you can't derive this information. You'd be better off marking the object in some way (create a `isDead` property) and write your functions/classes so that when they encounter `isDead == true` they can remove the reference.

Or only use one `Array` for storage, then you only have one place to remove it from

Comment: This is the best solution every thing I creat I call it from an array and when not needed I delete it from that array.. Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try event listeners. Something like so:

```
// Assuming Tank extends DisplayObject
public function setEnemy(newEnemy:Tank):void
{
    if (this.enemy)
    {
        this.enemy.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onEnemyRemoved); 
    }
    this.enemy = newEnemy;
    this.enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onEnemyRemoved); 
}

private function onEnemyRemoved(e:Event):void
{
    this.enemy.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onEnemyRemoved);
    this.enemy = null;
}
```

Comment: So, if tank1 is spotted by tank2 and tank3, then there is two references of tank1 inside tank2 and tank3, and also two event listeners waiting tank1 to be removed from stage, so when that happen tank2 and tank3 references will be set to null by these two event listeners...

Using listeners is an Excellent idea, thanks so much...